# Differing Character Display In Admin & User Accounts Despite Same Settings

Tags: ubuntu, keyboard, fonts, language

OS: Ubuntu 22.04.2

Machine: Dell Inspiron 15 Series 5000

I have the same languages and same keyboards installed in both my admin and user accounts.

The input method for the keyboard is iBus in both accounts. The browser (Firefox) settings in each account are also identical.

However, for text reading and input to **some web applications**, I see different rendering of certain characters, e.g. accented characters.

I just cannot understand this.

For offline use, e.g. text input to LibreOffice Writer, graphics packages (GIMP/Inkscape/etc) and so on, accented characters work as intended.

For many web applications accented characters work as intended.
But for a small few (usually online forum type applications) this is a nuisance.

I can work around the issue by unchecking the *Allow web pages to choose font ...* option in Firefox settings. But this gives me a gauche font choice for that website - and it shouldn't be necessary anyway since the admin account on the same machine renders the accented characters properly.

Anyone got any ideas on fixing this ?